# Direct systems and their homomorphisms.

Tags: abstract-algebra

In [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit#Algebraic_objects) Wikipedia article on direct systems, the $f_{ij}:A_i\to A_j$ are homomorphisms with the two properties

1. $f_{ii}$ is the identity of $A_i$,
2. $f_{ik}=f_{jk}\circ f_{ij}$ for all $i\leq j\leq k$.

Being homomorphisms does this mean (*) the $f_{ij}$ must also satisfy $f_{ij}(x+_iy)=f_{ij}(x)+_jf_{ij}(y)$ and $f_{ij}(x\times_iy)=f_{ij}(x)\times_jf_{ij}(y)$, or do these functions simply have to meet the two stated properties ?

I'm a little confused about this because, supposing I want to add an element of $A_5$ to $A_7$, say. I should be able to make the element in $A_5$ amenable to addition to an element in $A_7$, but then how could I perform $x+_7 y$ when $x\in A_5$ and $y\in A_7$... I can see how I can do this if I don't need (*) because I could use the $f_{ij}$ to go from $A_5$ to $A_7$ and then perform the addition within $A_7$ using $A_7$'s addition operation.

Comment: What is your intent in using this definition? The term "homomorphism" means a homomorphism preserving any structure you want to exist in the limit. If you want it to be a ring, for example, they must be homomorphisms of rings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am somewhat surprised by this question but I shall give as detailed explination as possible. A general homomorphism is on on an algebraic structure that has a set $S$ and one or several $n$-ary operations, for the general case I will denote it $f^S(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ from $S^n$ to $S$, of course if it is binary we just write as we usually do.

A homomorphism $\varphi:S\to T$ satisfies this identity then
$$\varphi(f^S(x_1,\ldots,x_n))=f^T(\varphi(x_1),\ldots,\varphi(x_n))$$
where $S$ and $T$ are the same kind of structures, both rings or groups or whatever, what it essentially means is that the function, aka homomorphism, respects the algebraic structure we have imposed. That means **ALL** $n$-ary operations.

For a group we have 
$$\varphi(ab)=\varphi(a)\varphi(b)$$
for a ring we have also
$$\varphi(a+b)=\varphi(a)+\varphi(b)$$
That is also why it is important to state the structure in question as it determines all the operations. Fortunately for you here it works on just about any as long as you are aware of the universal definition prior.

You cannot however have as you did $x+_7 y$ with $x\in A_5$ and $y\in A_7$ because the binary operation $+_7$ is not defined for elements in $A_5$! It is only defined for elements in $A_7$. However what you CAN do is have it
$$f_{5,7}(x)+_7+y$$
for elements, now the homomorphism $f_{5,7}$ sends an element in $A_5$ to an element in $A_7$ and as such the operation is defined and meaningful.

It is important to keep in mind that each $A_i$ is their own algebraic structure with their own $n$-ary operations that are only defined on $A_i$ and not the other $A_j$'s, with $i\neq j$. As such we must use a homomorphism to transfer it.

For substructures we tend to get a bit sloppy because we have the inclusion homomorphism $\imath$ and as such it tends to be omitted as it is injective. But that is abuse of notation for simplicity as we all understand we still NEED that homomorphism when we view substructures as their own structure.

Comment: So I should define separate addition/multiplication operations in the direct system, e.g. $\clubsuit:A_i\times A_j\to A_j$, where $i\leq j$ and $x\clubsuit y=f_{ij}(x)+_j y$. Is this all perfectly ok to do? In my mind I was stuck trying to work purely within the definition of direct system, which is why I was getting confused; I had not thought to add operations separate to the underlying rings into the mix.

Comment: Yes such a definition is okey, it is used in several. You need to keep all those things seperate and know that homomorphisms are what connects them.

Comment: An example I can take is is semidirect produgt $G\rtimes H$, where $(g_1,h_1)\cdot(g_2,h_2)=(g_1\varphi_{h_1}(g_2),h_1h_2)$ where $\varphi_{h_1}$ is an endomorphism for $G$ which depends on on $h_1$, that is we have a function from $H$ to $\text{End}(G)$. Using similar and assuming that we use a specific function $\varphi:H\to\text{End}(G)$ we can define a multiplication $G\times H$ where $gh$ makes sense, it is of course quite a bit of abuse of notation from known knowledge.